# Why do I get different results in Entity Framework and SQL Server transaction?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

In my EF code and SQL Server, I try to insert a user data while this user is not exist, but EF inserted it 1000 times, just 1 time in SQL Server.

EF code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            var count = db.Users.Count(f => f.Name == "Test");
            if (count > 0) continue;

            db.Users.Add(new User
            {
                Name = "Test",
                Gender = "Male",
                Phone = "1111111111",
                CreateTime = DateTime.Now
            });
        }

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            //1000 rows effected
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

T-SQL code:

```
declare @i int = 0
begin tran

while(@i < 1000)
    begin
        if not exists (select 1 from [dbo].[User] where Name = 'Test')
            insert into [dbo].[User] values('Test','Male','1111111111',getdate())
        set @i = @i + 1
    end

if(@@ERROR > 0)
    rollback tran
else
    commit tran
```

Even if I use a transaction wrap the EF code (but call `SaveChanges` once), the result is same as 1000 rows affected.

But when I use this code, the result is the same as in SQL Server:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    using (var trans = db.Database.BeginTransaction(ReadCommitted))
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            var count = db.Users.Count(f => f.Name == "Test");
            if (count > 0) continue;

            db.Users.Add(new User
            {
                Name = "Test",
                Gender = "Male",
                Phone = "1111111111",
                CreateTime = DateTime.Now
            });

            //1 row effected as sql does
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        try
        {
            trans.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me why transaction is different between EF and SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`db.Users.Add` does not insert. It makes for insertion when `SaveChanges` is called (what did you think `SaveChanges` did or why it was required if not for writing out changes that were previously *not* written?). That's why `db.Users.Count(f => f.Name == "Test")` always returns zero.

This has nothing to do with transactions.

(Btw, you probably should use `Any` instead of `Count` here).

Comment: even though i begin a transaction in ef code but only savechanges once out of foreach, it inserted 1000 times, while sql does not.  they are in a transaction(does sql inserted data when i dont commit?)

Comment: You merely repeated what you said in the question. How is that supposed to move things forward? In other words please explain what exactly you don't understand.